# Can the wp-plugins (Must Use Plugins) URL be targeted for use in functions.php?

Tags: functions, mu-plugins

Can the wp-plugins (Must Use Plugins) URL be targeted for use in functions.php? I have a mu-functions.php file in the mu-plugins folder. One function calls a javascript file (`alerts.js`) located in `example.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/js/`. How can I target the mu-plugins folder in my function?

Currently, I am using `get_site_url() . '/wp-content/mu-plugins/js/alerts.js',`

Although not completely relevant to the question, this is the complete function used to call the javascript file:

```
function load_my_alerts(){
      wp_register_script( 
        'my_alerts', 
        get_site_url() . '/wp-content/mu-plugins/js/alerts.js', 
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_alerts' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_alerts');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: this solution is not a best-practice. Please use the solution submitted by Nathan below!**

Use [the `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` and `WPMU_PLUGIN_URL` constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) :)

```
function load_my_alerts(){
    wp_register_script( 
        'my_alerts', 
        WPMU_PLUGIN_URL . '/js/alerts.js', 
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_alerts' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_alerts');
```

Comment: Thanks. I swear I used that. Maybe I missed the leading slash.

Comment: Please see my answer below, neither this nor the referenced answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, Nathan's example only works for regular plugins, not "Must Use Plugins". To make it work for MU plugins, you need to pass the invoking file:

```
plugins_url('/path/to/whatever', __FILE__)
```

Comment: Good looking out... https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L3166

Comment: using `__FILE__` won't give you the mu-plugins url when used in `functions.php` which is in the theme. Please see my answer below for a correct version.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to use constants. For this functionality one should ALWAYS use the `plugins_url()` function seen [here in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url).

```
    function load_my_alerts(){

        wp_register_script(
            'my_alerts',
            plugins_url('js/alerts.js'),
            array( 'jquery' )
        );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_alerts' );

    }

    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_alerts');
```

Comment: this won't give you the mu-plugins url when used in `functions.php` which is in the theme.

Comment: @shahar yes it will. Read the description in the codex linked above.

Comment: your example is missing the `$path` parameter for `plugins_url()` which is necessary to return the mu-plugins directory when used outside of an mu-plugin. See my answer below for a correct working example.

Comment: @NathanPowell [looking at the source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/), I think @shahar may be correct - this function is a lot dumber than one would hope. It looks like it only uses the MU path if the second argument is present and starts with the MU directory filepath. Stupidly, it seems that the "best practice" might be to use your MU-plugin-directory-relative filepath as the first argument and the `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` constant as (or prepending) the second argument. A little ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

When using `plugins_url()` outside of an mu-plugin, you need to specify the full path to the plugin that is in the `mu-plugins` directory. For example, when using it in a theme's `functions.php` file.

Below is a correct working version, where the second parameter of `plugins_url()` is a full path to the plugin in the `mu-plugins` directory.

Please see the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) for more info.

```
function load_my_plugin_script(){

    wp_register_script(
        'my_plugin_script',
        plugins_url('my_plugin.js', '/wp/wp-content/mu-plugins/my_plugin')
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_plugin_script' );

}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_plugin_script');
```